# Can type hinting infer type of class attribute from another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

There are subclasses that have the class attribute `matcher_function` set to a function.  During instantiation that function is called and sets another attribute `matcher`.  In all cases the return object of the `matcher_function` is what `matcher` gets set to.

Is it possible to create a type hint in the base class `BaseResolution` that would allow both mypy and pycharm to properly infer `matcher` is the return value of `matcher_function`?

```py
# contains_the_text.py
from hamcrest import contains_string
from hamcrest.library.text.stringcontains import StringContains
from .base_resolution import BaseResolution


class ContainsTheText(BaseResolution):
    matcher: StringContains  # <-- this is what I'm curious can be inferred
    matcher_function = contains_string  # <-- this function returns an instance 
                                        # of `StringContains`
    # it would be wonderful if 
    # a. mypy could detect that the matcher type hint is correct based on 'matcher_function' 
    # b. infer what the type is when the hint is not present in the subclasses.
```

```py
# base_resolution.py
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar

from hamcrest.core.base_matcher import BaseMatcher, Matcher
from hamcrest.core.description import Description

T = TypeVar("T")

class BaseResolution(BaseMatcher[T]):
    matcher: Matcher
    matcher_function: Callable
    expected: Any

    def __init__(self, *args: object, **kwargs: object) -> None:
        cls = self.__class__
        if args and kwargs:
            self.expected = (args, kwargs)
            self.matcher = cls.matcher_function(*args, **kwargs)
        elif args:
            self.expected = args if len(args) > 1 else args[0]
            self.matcher = cls.matcher_function(*args)
        elif kwargs:
            self.expected = kwargs
            self.matcher = cls.matcher_function(**kwargs)
        else:
            self.expected = True
            self.matcher = cls.matcher_function()

    def _matches(self, item: T) -> bool:
        """passthrough to the matcher's method."""
        return self.matcher.matches(item)

    # truncated a whole bunch of other methods...
```

While these are likely better typehints, they didn't seem to do the trick.

```py
class BaseResolution(BaseMatcher[T]):
    matcher: Matcher[T]
    matcher_function: Callable[..., Matcher[T]]
```

---

I know you can do something sorta similar using `TypeVar(bound=)` which will infer function return types based on arguments passed in.  But I can't seem to figure out how (if even possible) to apply that at a class attribute level.

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar, Generic
T = TypeVar("T")


class Foo(Generic[T]):
    ...

class FooBar(Foo[T]):
    ...

F = TypeVar("F", bound=Foo)  # any instance subclass of Foo


class MyClass(FooBar):
    ...

def bar(f: Type[F]) -> F:
    ...

def baz(f: Type[Foo]) -> Foo:
    ...


objx = bar(MyClass)
objy = baz(MyClass)

reveal_type(objx)  # -> MyClass*
reveal_type(objy)  # -> Foo[Any]
```

Given the above example I tried the following but that clearly isn't right.

```py
F = TypeVar("F", bound=Matcher)

class BaseResolution(BaseMatcher[T]):
    matcher: F
    matcher_function: Callable[..., F]

# mypy returns 
# Type variable "base_resolution.F" is unbound
```

Comment: `BaseResolution` has to be generic in `F` as well as `T`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  `Matcher` inherits `Generic` and `BaseMatcher` inherits `Matcher`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know how that worked:  `class BaseResolution(BaseMatcher[T])` should be `class BaseResolution(BaseMatcher[T], Generic[T, F])`.